# Laravel 5 splash screen returns row of question marks

Tags: php, windows, wamp, composer-php, laravel-5

I've been looking for an answer to this issue for a day or so now since I'm sure the solution is trivial but I can't seem to find it.

On a fresh install of Laravel 5 through `composer create-project` I get a splash screen that looks like this:

[image: Laravel 5 fresh installation splash screen]

It's very faint but there is a line of question marks running along the top of the page.

I'm running Windows 8.1 with WAMP 2.5.

Some searching threw up some answers regarding the addition of `detect_unicode = off` in my php.ini file but this hasn't solved it (and I've ensured I'm editing the correct `php.ini` file what with there being several using WAMP).

Composer was installed using the Windows `.exe` file and oddly enough, I have other Laravel 5 projects running on the same machine without any issue. As a test I push the site exactly as it is to the live server (a unix machine) where it displays correctly.

Laravel itself doesn't report any errors.

Other possible answers seem to point to a BOM in the files. I'm using PHP Storm for most of my editing but I'm unsure of how to remove any BOMs in the files.

Thanks.

Comment: If you use Notepad++ you can see what encoding the file has more clearly (assumingly your Blade template files)

Comment: @silkfire Thanks, I've gone and tried that with Notepad++ and it reports that the  `welcome.blade.php` file is UTF8 without BOM. Had it been just UTF8 that might have explained it.

Comment: If you try adding some text to the blade file at a certain location, could you pinpoint the source of the strange characters perhaps?

Comment: @silkfire It's odd. The file begins with the `<html>, <head>` tag etc in the editor, however inspecting the code with Chrome DevTools show the `<head>` tag to be empty as if the markup jumps out into the `<body>` tag. It's immediately after the `<body>` tag that the sting of questions marks appears.

Comment: This usually happens when you have a BOM mark or some garbage data in your file =/ Could you possibly inpect the file in a hex editor and/or try to remove those invisible characters? :)

Comment: @silkfire Thanks again for the input. I've also tried inspecting the files with TotalCommander (a Hex Editor) to try and discover any stray characters but it returns each file as clean.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75192/discussion-between-silkfire-and-chris-j).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It could be because your precompiled files may have been corrupted somehow along the way.

Try deleting the file `compiled.php` inside the `/vendor/` folder and run `composer update` from the command line right after.

Comment: After a lot of investigation, this was the answer that worked for me. Thanks.